# Ruby array of objects

Tags: ruby, object

Creating a class Square which has a constructor and a methiod to calculate the area of the square.

```
class Square
  def initialize(side)
    @side = side
  end

  def printArea
    @area = @side * @side
    puts "Area is: #{@area}"
  end
end
```

Creating 2 objects and adding them to an array

```
array = []
array << Square.new(4)
array << Square.new(10)

for i in array do
  array[i].printArea
end
```

How do i acces the objects inside the array? I get an error: no implicit conversion of Square into Integer.

Comment: You may also wish to push two objects in one line like: `array.push Square.new(4), Square.new(10)
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` construct is hardly ever used in Ruby code. Instead you'd write:

```
array.each do |square|
  square.printArea
end
```

This iterates over the array and returns each `square` object, which is what your code does as well. `i` is not an index, it's an element in the array.

As a note, Ruby strongly encourages method names and variables to be of the form `print_area`.

A more Ruby form of this code looks like this:

```
class Square
  attr_accessor :side

  def initialize(side)
    @side = side.to_i
  end

  def area
    @side * @side
  end
end

squares = [ ]
squares << Square.new(10)
squares << Square.new(20)

squares.each do |square|
  puts 'Square of side %d has area %d' % [ square.side, square.area ]
end
```

This consolidates your *display logic* outside of the *model* where you should be focused on other things.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i can't believe it was that easy.I usually alternate between for and each, but i'll use each for now on. I'll write down your suggestions so i can further improve the way i code.

Comment: Would it better to write your `area` method as `side*side` employing the wrapper?

Comment: Matter of preference. `@side * @side` is marginally faster, but that's irrelevant for most cases. `side * side` would work just the same.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers explained what to do to fix. I intend to explain WHY you got that error.

Pay attention to your code:

```
array = []
array << Square.new(4)
array << Square.new(10)

for i in array do
    array[i].printArea
end
```

You created an empty array and then inserted two Square instances in it, right?

Then, when you wrote `for i in array do`, what do you think `i` would contain? Of course `i` would contain the objects **in `array`**, i.e., `i` would contain the Square instances!!! You are saying it! `i in array` says `i` is the content of the positions of the array, not its index.

If you write

```
for i in array do
    p i.class
end
```

you'll see something like

```
Square
Square
```

It happens that Ruby only accepts integer as array indexes. Then, when you mentioned `array[i]` you were, in fact, saying something like `array[Square]`, and Ruby was trying to see those Square object as integers, in order to use them as array indexes. And it was failing, of course, because there is `no implicit conversion of Square into Integer`, and this is the error you got.

I explain a bit more about this is [this article](http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/06/implicit-and-bad-type-conversion-example.html) of my blog.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to say:

```
array.each do |sq| 
  sq.printArea 
end
```